# Connection string for Windows Forms application to access a SQL Server CE database in Windows Phone

Tags: string, windows-phone, connection, sql-server-ce

I need to access my SQL Server CE database that is located in Windows Phone from a Windows application that runs on my computer. I use Linq to Sql.

What connection string can find that isolated data folder on the cell phone?

Comment: There is no way to do that...

Comment: thank you so much for your fast reply. so, have you code for copy database of mobile to computer ? and copy from computer to mobile? using C# code. i do not want using tools.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Windows Phone there are several tools you can employ to access the isolated storage of a Windows Phone app running on the emulator or an actual device.

What you basically want to do is to copy the isolated storage to your PC (or at least parts of it) and then access your SQL database like a local file. You can then copy all the contents back.

One option is the IsolatedStorageExplorer. You can get the connected device id:

```
ISETool.exe EnumerateDevices
```

..and then take a snapshot of the entire isostore and write it to your PC:

```
ISETool.exe ts deviceindex:[id] f8ce6878-0aeb-497f-bcf4-65be961d4bba c:\data\myfiles
```

Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx

If triggering an external tool / running command line scripts is not an option for you then you might want to check out the code on CodePlex. These tools are open source (however: read the license!). Should be worth to check out the source code:

https://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/

http://wptools.codeplex.com/releases/view/97029

https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/

Comment: oh no, thank you friend. i know all of your ways that you remind me, but in real, i want not use tools, i just want do this operation by code c#.

Comment: Then head over to CodePlex and look at the source code.